# Thread save map in text template

Tags: templates, go

I wrote thread safe map using RWMutex. You can see code below.

```
type SyncMap struct {
    sync.RWMutex
    db map[string]interface{}
}

func NewSyncMap() *SyncMap {
    ctx := new(SyncMap)
    ctx.Clear()
    return ctx
}

func (ctx *SyncMap) Set(key string, value interface{}) {
    ctx.Lock()
    ctx.db[key] = value
    ctx.Unlock()
}

func (ctx *SyncMap) Get(key string) interface{} {
    ctx.RLock()
    v := ctx.db[key]
    ctx.RUnlock()
    return v
}

func (ctx *SyncMap) Delete(key string) {
    ctx.Lock()
    delete(ctx.db, key)
    ctx.Unlock()
}
```

And after I need to execute **template.Template** and put there that map.
I have two variant:

1. Make full copy of map (Not my idea of fun)
2. Just put reference to **Map.db** inside

```
func (ctx *SyncMap) Map() map[string]interface{} {
    return ctx.db
}
```

But is it thread safe for reading?

Answer (score 0):

> Map access is unsafe only when updates are occurring. As long as all goroutines are only reading—looking up elements in the map, including iterating through it using a for range loop—and not changing the map by assigning to elements or doing deletions, it is safe for them to access the map concurrently without synchronization.
>   https://golang.org/doc/faq#atomic_maps

Exposing the internal map removes the protection you implemented. However, I think you can call the methods of your type SyncMap in the templates instead of accessing the internal map.

Have you already considered using another types like this one? https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Map